# embedded image in htm document not visible while signing in Docusign

Tags: html, image, docusignapi

C# restapi client was used to create envelope with document

```
doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
doc.Name = "TestFile.htm";
```

For embedding image in htm document i have unsuccessfully used these options
    Option1  img src  data:image/png;base64
    Option 2 img src data:image/svg+xml;
  Reference for option 2 https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/

I guess with option 1 ,there is issue of double encoding as base64 .

Request help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create an mhtml style of html and upload it as an html file. It can include images.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML